# best way to run multi-threaded nunit tests

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, nunit

I currently trying to find a solution, how to ensure that a test fails if an exception occurs in a thread which is spawn by the test method.

I DON'T want to start a discussion about more than one thread in a unit test. => "unit test".Replace("unit","integration");

I already read a lot of threads in several forums, I know about [CrossThreadTestRunner](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/post/NUnit-and-Multithreaded-Tests-CrossThreadTestRunner.aspx), but I'm searching for a solution whichs integrates into nunit, and does not require to rewrite a lot of tests.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating an addin for nunit, which "installs" an ITestDecorator.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Please provide some information on what you've done to make it work. This isn't an answer to the question at all.

Comment: @Martin Moser Please elaborate

Answer (score 3):

The reason that exceptions on non-test threads (i.e. other spawned threads) do not cause tests to fail is that NUnit is configured by default to use [legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx) which is a .Net process level setting which can be applied via app.config, i.e.:

```
<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
```

Enabling this setting (i.e. setting it to "1") causes exceptions which do not occur on the main thread to be *ignored*.

I wrote an article which goes into more detail in reference to this issue with the ReSharper test runner, but it applies equally to the NUnit test runner:
https://web.archive.org/web/20101006004301/http://gojisoft.com/blog/2010/05/14/resharper-test-runner-hidden-thread-exceptions/)

> ### ReSharper test runner – hidden thread exceptions
>
> By Tim Lloyd, May 14, 2010 4:31 pm
>
> We use the ReSharper test runner here at GojiSoft to run NUnit tests
> from within Visual Studio. It’s a great test runner, but doesn’t play
> nicely with multi-threaded components where exceptions may occur on
> non-test threads. Unhandled exceptions on non-test threads are hidden
> and tests which should fail, instead pass.
>
> ...
>
> The problem lies in the fact that the ReSharper test runner is
> configured to behave in the same way as .Net 1.0 and 1.1 apps where
> unhandled exceptions on non-main threads were swallowed. The situation
> improves from .Net 2.0 where all unhandled exceptions flatten the
> process. However, Microsoft had to allow existing .Net 1.0 and 1.1
> apps the option of behaving as before on new .Net frameworks. They
> introduced the app.config setting: legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy.
>
> The ReSharper test runner is configured by default to use the .Net 1.0
> and 1.1 policy, so if there is an unhandled non-test thread exception
> it does not bubble up and cause the test to fail – the test passes,
> and we get a false positive instead.
>
> If unhandled exceptions on non-test threads should fail tests, the
> app.config for the ReSharper test runner has to be updated.
>
> ...
>
> 3. Turn the legacy unhandled exception policy off by editing legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy: `<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="0" />`
> 4. Now multi-threaded tests fail as expected when they raise exceptions on non-test threads:
>
> Buyer beware…
>
> There is a caveat to this. Exceptions on non-test threads will now
> flattened the test runner and test suite execution will be halted when
> they happen. This is in contrast to normal test runs where failed
> tests are marked as failed, and the test runner continues. ...

Comment: This didn't work for me, the test still passed. But it did kill the test like the article said it would.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, my solution is to catch the exception and increment an exception counter, so the Test method just have to assert the exception counter is 0 to confirm no thread got an exception.

An extract of my test code once specific environment stuff is removed:

```
    const int MaxThreads = 25;
    const int MaxWait = 10;
    const int Iterations = 10;
    private readonly Random random=new Random();
    private static int startedThreads=MaxThreads ;
    private static int exceptions = 0;
```

…

```
[Test]
    public void testclass()
    {
        // Create n threads, each of them will be reading configuration while another one cleans up

        Thread thread = new Thread(Method1)
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Name = "MyThread0"
        };

        thread.Start();
        for (int i = 1; i < MaxThreads; i++)
        {
            thread = new Thread(Method2)
            {
                IsBackground = true,
                Name = string.Format("MyThread{0}", i)
            };

            thread.Start();
        }

        // wait for all of them to finish
        while (startedThreads > 0 && exceptions==0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(MaxWait);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(0, exceptions, "Expected no exceptions on threads");
    }

    private void Method1()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            {
            // Stuff being tested
                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(MaxWait));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Ërror in Method1 Thread {0}", exception);
            exceptions++;
        }
        finally
        {
            startedThreads--;
        }
    }

    private void Method2()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            {
                // Stuff being tested
                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(MaxWait));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Ërror in Method2 Thread {0}", exception);
            exceptions++;
        }
        finally
        {
            startedThreads--;
        }
    }
```